# Using package.el to install and update but use-package for loading and configuring

Tags: package, use-package

After recently learning about `use-package` I decided to port my configuration to it but found myself reluctant to give up the convenience of using `package.el` to install packages and keep them updated. I've found it a little tricky to combine `use-package` and `package.el`.

I'm generally interested in learning how people combine `use-package` with the `package.el` system, but for a more specific question, keep reading.

Here's what I want:

1. To have packages installed by the package manager so I can easily browse for packages and keep them updated through `list-packages`.
2. To configure and load packages exclusively through `use-package`, so I can easily see in my init file exactly what I'm loading and how it is configured.
3. Optionally, I'd like to also be able to install packages through `use-package`'s `:ensure` keyword.

If I'm understanding correctly I want very little of what `package-initialize` does, basically only the way it sets up the `load-path`. Currently I have this in my configuration:

```
;(package-initialize)
(setq package-enable-at-startup nil)
(let ((default-directory "~/.emacs.d/elpa"))
  (normal-top-level-add-subdirs-to-load-path))
(require 'use-package)
```

The first, commented, line is so Emacs 25 doesn't helpfully add a `(package-initialize)` to my init file. The bit with `normal-top-level-add-subdirs-to-load-path` is an approximation to what `package-initialize` would make the `load-path`, an approximation that seems good enough.

This seems to achieve my desires 1 and 2, but not 3. If I try to use `:ensure`, I get an error message saying that `package.el` is not initialized. Calling `package-initialize` would fix that, but I wish to avoid that since a) I don't want all the myriad autoloads to be loaded (I prefer to use `use-package` to create precisely the autoloads I need), and b) I want to be able to easily avoid loading certain installed packages whenever I want (which is easy to do with `use-package`).

Does anyone have a recommendation for how to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

IIUC what you want to do is:

```
(package-initialize t)
```

Note the `t` argument, which is the key to your happiness here since it will (or should, at least) initialize package.el without activating all the installed packages.

Comment: This answers my question, even though now I'm leaning towards using `package-initialize` which renders my question moot.

Answer (score 17):

With your current configuration, you've effectively *disabled* package.el, as you don't initialise the package manager and prevent Emacs from automatically initialising it.  All you do in return is to add ELPA to the `load-path`, but that's just a small subset of what package.el does.  I'm not sure why you do that, but it's not a setup that I'd recommend.

Specifically, you'll not get package autoloads with your approach, which means that initially no commands from any package will be available.

In other words, `M-x` will only offer you built-in commands.  To add in commands from your packages you'd have to add explicit `:commands` definitions to *all* your `use-package` declarations, which amounts to a **lot** of maintenance effort—particularly for large packages such as Magit—for essentially zero gain—package.el gives you autoloads for free.

---

Combining `use-package` with package.el is actually very simple—y entire setup is based on this combination—but it's much better to let package.el actually to its job.  Just initialise package.el at the very beginning of your init file:

```
(require 'package)
(setq package-enable-at-startup nil)   ; To prevent initialising twice
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "https://stable.melpa.org/packages/"))

(package-initialize)
```

For convenience you may subsequently want to bootstrap `use-package`, if it's not already installed:

```
(unless (package-installed-p 'use-package)
  (package-refresh-contents)
  (package-install 'use-package))
```

This let's you start an Emacs session on a fresh system, and your init.el will automatically install `use-package`.

Ultimately you need to load `use-package`:

```
(eval-when-compile
  (require 'use-package))
```

Now you can use `use-package` to install and configure packages:

```
(use-package magit                      ; The one and only Git frontend
  :ensure t
  :bind (("C-c v c" . magit-clone)
         ("C-c v v" . magit-status)
         ("C-c v g" . magit-blame)
         ("C-c v l" . magit-log-buffer-file)
         ("C-c v p" . magit-pull))
   :config (setq magit-save-repository-buffers 'dontask))
```

When Emacs now evaluates this form during startup, `use-package` will check whether Magit is already installed, and automatically install it if necessary.

Comment: "I'm not sure why you do that": the only reason I can see is about startup times: `package-initialize` takes some time to populate the path, define autoloads and do the rest of its stuff. I think I read somewhere that Jon Wiegley himself (the author of `use-package`) prefers declaring all autoloaded commands in `use-package` stanzas rather than relying on `package.el`.

Comment: Last time I looked he did not use package.el at all, and in any case, I don't think you'll gain a lot.  You need to populate the `load-path` and add autoloads in either case, whether via `use-package` or via `package.el`.  I doubt that there's a measurable difference, particularly if you've got a modern system with a fast disk.

Comment: Agreed. I did the timings myself. With a fast disk, you effectively don't see much of a difference. With a slow disk, the startup can be noticeably slower (something like 0.2s) with `package-initialize` than a custom list in `load-path`. I attribute this to the "exploration" of the filesystem that `package.el` does. However, I never measured any significant difference in performance between loading `autoload` definitions from files and having them in `use-package` stanzas.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't say I've *disabled* the `package.el` system, I'd say I only disabled `package-initialize`! The reason is that while I like `list-packages` to browse for new packages and specially to update all my currently installed packages, I think I prefer the targeted loading of `use-package`. For me having autoloads only for commands I use sounds like a good thing!

Comment: Also, less philosophically, I don't like the interaction between `package-initialize` and `:diminish` (for deferred `use-package` declarations): `package-initialize` will give me the default configuration, typically including advertising on mode lines; and diminish only kicks in the first time I use a command I `:bind` or declare with `:commands`.

Comment: Is it fair to say you think my goal of having `use-package` load *and* configure my packages is misguided and you would recommend having `package-initialize` load and `use-package` only configure?

Comment: @OmarAntolín-Camarena Uhm, `:diminish` doesn't have anything to do with how you enable a package.  I'd not say your goal is “misguided”, but it's creating a lot of needless redundant work for you :)

Comment: I didn't explain my complaint about `:diminish` well. I should ask a separate question about it. I'm not sure what you mean by "needless redundant work". Do you mean that with `use-package` I'd have to use `:commands` occasionally to get some autoloads that `package-initialize` would give me? If so, that's minimal, usually `:bind` gives me all the autoloads I need.

Comment: @OmarAntolín-Camarena You'll also need `:modes` for all auto mode entries that major mode packages would normally add via autoloads.  Also, you need to add `:commands` not only for your own needs, but also for autoloads that other packages expect.

Comment: Right, I forgot to mention `:modes`, which I think are reasonable to expect I should add by hand, but the other thing you mentions is troublesome: I didn't know that sometimes packages expect certain autoloads from *other* packages! That sounds awful. I don't think package authors should do that, but if they do I certainly don't want to deal with the consequences. I think you've convinced me to use `package-initialize` defensively.

Comment: @OmarAntolín-Camarena Why not?  Autoloads are essentially the public interface of a user-facing package, and since package.el became the standard way of distributing packages we can rely upon their presence.