# Defer loading packages with use-package and package manager

Tags: init-file, package, use-package

How can I defer loading a package when it is installed using package.el with use-package? Basically, I want the package I use to only be activated using `use-package` instead of `package-initialize` so that this snippet would produce an error:

```
(use-package company
  :init
  (global-company-mode)
  (message "Company mode enabled globally"))
```

(and changing `:init` to `:config` would work as expected)

Answer (score 2):

I have found the answer here: [Using package.el to install and update but use-package for loading and configuring](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/16831/15575)

Basically, you can use package.el to manage packages and call `(package-initialize t)` to setup load paths but not activate them.

Answer (score 1):

while I don't know the specific answer to your question, `use_package` supports `:defer n` which will defer loading the package containing :defer for n seconds.

there is also `:disabled` which may be of help to you.

As a complete example, the use-package author John Wiegley uses this snippet for `which-key`:

```
(use-package which-key
  :disabled t
  :load-path "site-lisp/which-key"
  :diminish which-key-mode
  :commands which-key-mode
  :defer 10
  :config
  (which-key-mode 1))
```